# With statement sets variable to None

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to run this code:

```
class A:
    def __enter__(self):
        print "enter"
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print "exit"
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
with A(10) as a:
    print a.i
```

And I get this error:

```
enter
exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".last_tmp.py", line 9, in <module>
print a.i
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'i'
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to return `self` from `__enter__`:

```
def __enter__(self):
    print "enter"
    return self
```

Your `with` statement is effectively equivalent to:

```
a = A(10).__enter__()  # with A(10) as a:
try:
    print a.i  # Your with body
except:
    a.__exit__(exception and type)
    raise
else:
    a.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

So, you need to return something, otherwise `a` will have the value of `None` (default return value), and `None` does not have an attribute named `i`, so you get an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of the object's `__enter__` method is what is assigned to the name following the `as` keyword. Your method (implicitly) returns `None`, resulting in the error you see. Instead, `__enter__` should return `self`, so that the object created by `A(10)` is assigned to `a`.